# Find maximum sum of sublist in list of positive integers under O(n^2) of specified length Python 3.5

Tags: python, algorithm, sublist, maximize

For one of my programming questions, I am required to define a function that accepts two variables, a list of length l and an integer w. I then have to find the maximum sum of a sublist with length w within the list.

Conditions:

1<=w<=l<=100000

Each element in the list ranges from [1, 100]

Currently, my solution works in O(n^2) (correct me if I'm wrong, code attached below), which the autograder does not accept, since we are required to find an even simpler solution.

My code:

```
def find_best_location(w, lst):
    best = 0
    n = 0
    while n <= len(lst) - w:
        lists = lst[n: n + w]
        cur = sum(lists)
        best = cur if cur>best else best
        n+=1

    return best
```

If anyone is able to find a more efficient solution, please do let me know! Also if I computed my big-O notation wrongly do let me know as well!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Find sum `current` of first `w` elements, assign it to `best`.
2) Starting from `i = w`: `current = current + lst[i]-lst[i-w]`, `best = max(best, current)`.
3) Done.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is indeed `O(n^2)` (or `O(n*W)` if you want a tighter bound)

You can do it in O(n) by creating an aux array `sums`, where:

```
sums[0] = l[0]
sums[i] = sums[i-1] + l[i]
```

Then, by iterating it and checking `sums[i] - sums[i-W]` you can find your solution in linear time

You can even calculate `sums` array on the fly to reduce space complexity, but if I were you, I'd start with it, and see if I can upgrade my solution next.

Comment: Hi could you explain your solution in more depth? I do not quite understand why it works. Furthermore, when you say "by iterating it and checking" what does the "it" refer to? Thanks!

Comment: @RussellNg `a[i+1] + ... + a[i+W] = a[0] + a[1] + ... + a[i+W] - (a[0] + a[1] + ... + a[i])`\

Comment: Oh I see...Thanks for explaining!